# How to add a new column to a set of Function records

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, record

I'm creating a function that returns a set of records from a table titled "Sequence". As part of this table, I am also analyzing another table ("Log_Alpha") and inserting appropriate information into the record. To date what I have done is overwrite an existing columns data, and then rename the column afterwards in my select call to the function (IE SELECT * FROM Production1(parameters) as tbl(xxx,xxx,xxx,NewColumnName Real,xxx,xxx...)

This works very well, however I need to retain the original data and therefore would prefer to rather add a new column to the record. But how do I do this, as the record is grabbing its column names directly from the table "Sequence".

My code shows **rc."seqLogsIn"** being the column where (average daily SED) data is being captured. This then gets called from the database by the SELECT query seen at the bottom of this code, where the column is renamed to **"AvLogSED"**.

Here is the complete function, however you really only need to focus on the **SELECT AVG("logSED")** section.

To clarify, I want to create a new column in the record (called AvLogSED, as part of the function) and inject the data into that new column, instead of "misappropriating" seqLogsIn. How do I do that?

I am running PostgreSQL 9.2.9, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 64-bit on a Windows 7 desktop PC (local server copy also running on desktop).

```
-- Function: production1(timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone)    
-- DROP FUNCTION production1(timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION production1(tme1 timestamp without time zone, tme2 timestamp without time zone)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  rc Record;
  tmeA timestamp without time zone;
  tmeB timestamp without time zone;
  AverageSED Real;

BEGIN

tmeA := tme1 + '1 day'::interval;
tmeB := tme2 + '1 day'::interval;

-- get average SED for all logs in time/date range
SELECT AVG("logSED")::Real
  FROM "Log_Alpha"
  WHERE "logTime" >= DATE_TRUNC('DAY', tme1) AND "logTime" < DATE_TRUNC('DAY', tme2 + '1 day'::interval) -- Calculate average for each day from 00:00 hours from first day thru to 23:59:59.99 for last day
  INTO averageSED;

  FOR rc IN 
    SELECT *, averageSED 
    FROM "Sequence"
    WHERE "Sequence"."seqMinute" = 150 AND "Sequence"."seqTime" >= tmeA AND "Sequence"."seqTime" <= tmeB
    ORDER BY "Sequence"."seqTime" 

  LOOP
    rc."seqTime" = rc."seqTime" - '1 day'::interval;

    -- Use a subquery to calculate the average SED for all logs for the day pertaining to this record date field
    SELECT AVG("logSED")::Real into rc."seqLogsIn" FROM "Log_Alpha" -- Replace column seqLogsIn data from sequence table with Daily Average SED data. The column title can be renamed in function (SELECT) call as required
      WHERE "Log_Alpha"."logTime" >= DATE_TRUNC('DAY', rc."seqTime") and "Log_Alpha"."logTime" < (DATE_TRUNC('DAY', rc."seqTime") + '1 day'::interval); -- Date truncated (always start at 00:00 hours of the day) to counter offset induced by mn variable

    RETURN NEXT rc;  
  END LOOP;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION production1(timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

This is the select function call that "renames" the appropriate column to AvLogSED.

```
select * from production1('2016-02-27 00:00:00','2016-03-11 00:00:00') as tbl(seqTime timestamp without time zone,seqMinute integer,AvLogSED Real,seqLogVolIn Real,seqFinishedVol Real,seqChipTonnes Real,seqSawdustTonnes Real,seqBinSortVol Real,seqTraySortVol Real,seqFlitchSortVol Real,seqBinSortPieces Real,seqTraySortPieces Real,seqFlitchSortPieces Real,seqBinSortRejects Real,seqBinSortSlash Real,seqTraySortRejects Real,seqTraySortSlash Real,seqCanterCants Real,seqSecBandCants Real,seqSecBandRecycled Real,seqCS1Cants Real,seqCS3Cants Real,seqE1Pieces Real,seqE1ManualRejects Real,seqE1OperatorRejects Real,seqE1ThicknessRejects Real,seqE1NoSortRejects Real,seqE1VolumeIn Real,seqE1VolumeOut Real,seqE2Pieces Real,seqE2ManualRejects Real,seqE2OperatorRejects Real,seqE2ThicknessRejects Real,seqE2NoSortRejects Real,seqE2VolumeIn Real,seqE2VolumeOut Real,seqE1Bypass Real,seqE2Bypass Real,seqBSVolumeIn Real,seqPrimaryRuntime Real,seqBinLugSpeed Real,seqBinLugFill Real,seqTrayLugSpeed Real,seqTrayLugFill Real,seqCompressor1kWh Real,seqCompressor2kWh Real,seqCompressor3kWh Real,seqCompressor4kWh Real,seqKiln1and2GJ Real,seqKiln3GJ Real,seqKiln4GJ Real,seqKiln5GJ Real,seqKiln6GJ Real,seqKiln7GJ Real,seqKiln8GJ Real,seqKiln9GJ Real,seqKiln10GJ Real,seqKiln11GJ Real,seqKiln12GJ Real,seqFlitchTray10 Real,seqFlitchReturn Real,seqBSLiftOut Real,seqSecCantRuntime Real,seqSecBandRuntime Real,seqSecCS1Runtime Real,seqSecCS3Runtime Real,seqEdger1Runtime Real,seqEdger2Runtime Real,seqBinSorterRuntime Real,seqTraySorterRuntime Real,seqFlitchSorterRuntime Real,seqReEntryE1Minutes Real,seqReEntryChipMinutes Real,seqAwaitingLogs Real,seqBSUtilisation Real,seqTSUtilisation Real,seqFSUtilisation Real,seqDebarkerRuntime Real,seqReEntryChipCount Real,seqReEntryE1Count Real,Reserved2 Real,Reserved3 Real,Reserved4 Real,Reserved5 Real,Reserved6 Real,AverageSED Real)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return an arbitrary record like this:

```
RETURN NEXT ROW(val1, val2, ...);
```

That way you are not limited by an existing type.

Comment: I've tried that: [RETURN NEXT rc(seqTime timestamp without time zone,seqMinute integer,seqLogsIn Real,seqLogVolIn Real...); ] but I get an error returned stating error at or near "(". Also tried with and without datatypes.

Comment: You should *not* return `rc(val1, val2, ...)`, which is a syntax error, but `ROW(val1, val2, ...)`. `ROW` is a keyword to be taken literally.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was found to be as follows:

```
FOR rc IN
    SELECT *, AverageSED, avDailySED
    FROM "Sequence"
    WHERE "Sequence"."seqMinute" = mn AND "Sequence"."seqTime" >= tmeA AND "Sequence"."seqTime" <= tmeB
    ORDER BY "Sequence"."seqTime"
  LOOP
```

By adding AverageSED and avDailySED to SELECT, these columns were automatically added to the rc record. One hook that I discovered was that I had to also explicitly push data into avDailySED in record rc. By this I mean my existing line of code:

```
SELECT AVG("logSED")::Real into avDailySED FROM "Log_Alpha" -- Store average SED value in new column
```

Would result in a blank avDailySED column. Changing to this solved the issue:

```
SELECT AVG("logSED")::Real into rc.avDailySED FROM "Log_Alpha" -- Store average SED value in new column
```